# How to evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos\left(\frac{t x}{\lambda} \right)}{t^ 3}\, \left(\int_0^t s^2\cos (s)\, ds\right)\, dt $?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

This is a problem I encountered in the context of Fourier Transform. I tried to use convolution and transforms, but I didn't have much advance. I would be grateful for any helpful tips.

Comment: You can do the integral in $s$ by parts twice

Comment: That’s right, but and then? That’s the question!